# Use apache sshd ssh client got error "No detected/configured" IoServiceFactoryFactory

Tags: java, ssh, apache-mina

I want to use apache sshd project http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/ to connect a network switch:

```
public void connect(){ 

    try 
    { 
      client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient(); 
      client.start(); 
      session=client.connect(account, host, port).getSession(); 
      session.addPasswordIdentity(password); 
      session.auth().verify(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
       System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    } 
}
```

but got error:

Use apache sshd ssh client got error "No detected/configured" IoServiceFactoryFactory

how to fix it?Thanks

and I can't find in the doc whether the apache sshd project suppurt ssh protocol 1.5?this device use ssh 2.0,but my other device use ssh 1.5,thanks